# How to restart Budgie desktop?

Tags: desktop-environment, budgie

How to restart the Budgie desktop (Solus Linux, Ubuntu Budgie) without logging out?

---

Posted in order to provide the answer.

Answer (score 6):

[Source](https://www.reddit.com/r/SolusProject/comments/7pfeew/is_there_a_simple_proper_way_to_restart_budgie/dsgrv7w/)~

The command is `nohup budgie-panel --replace&`. (That's for the current version no 10, GTK : the future version 11 is [said to be qt-based](https://budgie-desktop.org/2017/01/25/kicking-off-budgie-11/) - and that will be another story.)

To call that with a click or two, use a shortcut - or, add a launcher - with `gedit`:

`gedit ~/.local/share/applications/restart-budgie.desktop`

then, paste the lines below - and save:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Restart budgie desktop
Icon=preferences-desktop
Categories=System;Settings;
Exec=sh -c 'nohup budgie-panel --replace&'
```